# Convert ambiguous grammar $S \to 01S1\mid SS\mid\epsilon$ to unambiguous grammar

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, formal-grammars, ambiguity

Given the ambiguous CFG :
$ S \to 01S1\mid SS\mid\epsilon $

I came up with the following CFG which I think is unambiguous:

$S \to 01X \mid 011X$
$X \to 01X1 \mid \epsilon$

Is my CFG unambiguous and does it represent the same language?

Comment: Have you tried *proving* your claims? This is how we know that a mathematical statement is true.

Comment: Your grammar generates $01$, which is not in the original language.

Comment: Tip: Replace $01$ with $($ and $1$ with $)$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $D$ be the given grammar, $S \mapsto01S1\mid SS\mid\epsilon$.
Then each word $w$ generated by $D$ is a mixture of equal number of $01$'s and $1$'s such that in any prefix of $w$ there are at least as many $1$'s as 0's but at most twice as many $1$'s as $0$'s.

Let $H$ be your grammar, $S \mapsto01X\mid011X$ and $X\mapsto 01X1\mid ϵ$.
Then each word generated by $X$ is some number of $01$'s followed by the same number of $1$'s. So each word $w$ generated by $H$ starts with $01$ or $011$, followed by some number of $01$'s, followed by the same number of $1$'s.

Both $D$ and $H$ are CFGs. While $D$ is ambiguous as illustrated by $011\ \  011011=011011\ \ 011$, $H$ is unambiguous.

The word $010111011$ is generated by $D$ but not by $H$. The word $01011$ is generated by $H$ but not by $D$. Hence, the language generated by $H$ is not the same as the given language generated by $D$.

It should not be hard to prove the various claims in the above paragraphs. Yuval Filmus' idea to treat $01$ as one symbol should be helpful.

---

Is the language generated by $D$ inherently ambiguous? Here is the spoiler.

> No. Here is a deterministic grammar for $D$
>  $$ S \mapsto \epsilon\mid 01S1S $$
>  Note that any deterministic grammar is non-ambiguous.
>  The language is actually isomorphic to the celebrated [Dyck language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyck_language), if we consider $01$ as the encoding of the left bracket and $1$ as the encoding of the right bracket.